# React permanently appends path to URL

Tags: reactjs, react-router-dom

I am using react-router-dom for navigation and all routing seems to work fine when using the navigation bar NavLinks. However, I created another component called 'ViewReport.js' that is 'NOT' part of the navigation bar NavLinks but is included in my routes. Users are redirected to this component when they click on a report id in order to display report details.

##### THIS IS WHERE THE ISSUE COMES IN:

###### using localhost:300 in order to not disclose the actual app

- After clicking a report id the user is routed to localhost:3000/reportapp/viewreport to display the report details.
- If the user clicks the Dashboard link in the navigation bar they are directed to localhost:3000/reportapp/viewreport/ instead of localhost:3000/reportapp.
- The same goes for any other link in the navigation bar such as /archive, /create, and /support. They all result in following when using the navigation bar form the ViewReport.js component.

  - **localhost:3000/reportapp/viewreport/create**
  - **localhost:3000/reportapp/viewreport/support**
  - **localhost:3000/reportapp/viewreport/archive**

The only way to actually get back to the Dashboard page is to manually change it in the url bar or to click the browser back button over and over till you reach the page prior to clicking the report id. What I am trying to do is actually route to the routes I have the NavLinks linked.

##### router code

```
function App() {
  return (
    <Router basename={`/${name}`}>
      <div>
        <Navbar />
        <Switch>
          <Route exact path="/" component={Dashboard} />
          <Route path="/Create" component={Create} />
          <Route path="/Archive" component={Archive} />
          <Route path="/Support" component={Support} />
          <Route path="/Resources" component={Resources} />
          <Route exact path="/ViewReport" component={ViewReport} />
        </Switch>
      </div>
    </Router>
  );
}

export default App;
```

##### Navigation Bar

```
<nav className="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark bg-dark">
  <div className="container-fluid">
    <button
      className="navbar-toggler"
      type="button"
      data-bs-toggle="collapse"
      data-bs-target="#navbarText"
      aria-controls="navbarText"
      aria-expanded="false"
      aria-label="Toggle navigation"
    >
      <span className="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>
    <div className="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarText">
      <ul className="navbar-nav me-auto mb-2 mb-lg-0">
        <li className="nav-item">
          <NavLink
            className="nav-link"
            aria-current="page"
            to="./"
            exact={true}
          >
            Dashboard
          </NavLink>
        </li>
        <li className="nav-item">
          <NavLink className="nav-link" to="./Create">
            Create Report
          </NavLink>
        </li>
        <li className="nav-item">
          <NavLink className="nav-link" to="./Archive">
            Archived Reports
          </NavLink>
        </li>
        <li className="nav-item">
          <NavLink className="nav-link" to="./Support">
            Support
          </NavLink>
        </li>
        <li className="nav-item">
          <NavLink className="nav-link" to="./Resources">
            Resources
          </NavLink>
        </li>
      </ul>
      <span className="navbar-text">
        <h2 className="amazon-orange titlestyle">Amazon FitTool</h2>
      </span>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>;
```

Comment: Can you show the full router code? What is the variable "name"? Also, you have a typo there, it is <Switch> not <switch>

Comment: Thank for your reply. {name} is imported from package.json and is is set to the name of the app. This is done because this is hosted on a sub-domain that other applications are hosted on so every path that is routed needs to be directly passed to the specific app. in this case {appname}/Dashboard and so on. Absolutely, just updated the original post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change

```
<NavLink className="nav-link" aria-current="page" to="./" exact={true}>Dashboard</NavLink>
```

to

```
<NavLink className="nav-link" aria-current="page" to="/" exact={true}>Dashboard</NavLink>
```

`./` to `/`.

And as you have said

> The same goes for any other link in the navigation bar

:P

E.g. `./Support` to `/Support`

Comment: Amazing. Thank you so much ... that worked!!   :)

Comment: "Amazing" , I just removed a `.` but I'm glad I could help :)

Comment: thanks it helps me too, in my case i forgot the /